# JavaEE: requestScope в jsp не видит атрибут

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, request, forward

У меня есть сервлет, где я с помощью контекста получаю Map объектов Task. Потом я закидываю все в атрибуты request и передаю этот request в jsp, но jsp не видит его. Через requestScope пытаюсь получить, но среда мне не предлагает выбрать tasks, так как его нет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class GetStartPageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private Map<Integer, Task> tasks;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        final Object tasks = getServletContext().getAttribute("tasks");

        if (tasks instanceof ConcurrentHashMap){
            this.tasks = (ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Task>) tasks;
        }else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Your repo does not initialize!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("tasks", tasks.values());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/start-page.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Сервис задач</title>
    <style>
        <%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css" %>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Все задачи</h2>
<c:forEach var="task" items="${requestScope.tasks}">
    <ul>
        Название: <c:out value="${task.title}"/> <br>
        Описание: <c:out value="${task.description}"/> <br>

        <form method="get" action="<c:url value='/update-task'/>">
            <input type="number" hidden name="id" value="${task.id}">
            <input type="submit" value="Редактировать">
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="<c:url value='/delete-task'/>">
            <input type="number" hidden name="id" value="${task.id}">
            <input type="submit" value="Удалить">
        </form>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
</c:forEach>
<h2>Создание новой задачи</h2>
<form method="post" action="<c:url value='/add-task'/>">
    <label>Название <input type="text" name="title"/></label><br>
    <label>Описание <input type="text" name="description"/></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" name="Ok"/>
</form>
<h2>Получить JSON задачи по id</h2>
<form method="get" action="<c:url value='/get-task'/>">
    <label>ID задачи <input type="number" name="id"></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Получить данные задачи" name="Ok"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <h2>Все задачи</h2>
<c:forEach var="task" items="${tasks}">
......
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]